# Why is my AR forecast better than my ARIMA forecast even though data is I(1)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, differencing

I am trying to build a time series model for forecasting. The time plot of the data is as shown

[image]

Evidently, there is a trend component and the series is not stationary. As the interest is in forecasting, I did a 90/10 train-test split (i.e., to forecast and compare with the last 10% of data). After performing a first difference on the train set, and executing Augmented Dickey Fuller (ADF) test, the differenced series is stationary. Upon trying various orders of p and q of AR and MA respectively, the model with the lowest AIC suggests p to be 2 and q to be 0 (i.e., ARIMA(2,1,0) model). The forecast of the ARIMA(2,1,0) model is as shown

[image]

and the MSE is 53.33. However, I have also tried forecasting with ARIMA(2,0,0) model and the results is as shown

[image]

and the MSE is 7.08, which is much much better than the ARIMA(2,1,0) model. Why would the ARIMA(2,0,0) model outperform the ARIMA(2,1,0) when differencing is required?

I have also looked into the model diagnostic, e.g., Ljung-Box statistic and ACF of residuals to ensure that the model does not violate relevant assumptions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Differencing is probably not required for this time series. (Check out the concept of *overdifferencing*.) By looking at the plot, it seems more plausible to me that the series follows a linear trend than a random walk.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for the reply, I understand that time series exhibiting non constant mean and variance are indicators of non-stationarity (in this case mean is non constant due to a linear trend). Therefore, differencing is required to induce stationarity. I also did an adf test on the raw series, and the results show that the series is non-stationary. Therefore, the motivation to take a first difference was clear to me. Do you mind elaborating more a bit on the concept of overdifferencing, and the circumstances where it becomes contradictory with the textbook approach?

Comment: A proper time series textbook would not recommend differencing a time series that does not contain a unit root, as that leads to overdifferencing and its implications (doubling the error variance is among them – you can see that in the width of your forecast intervals, just compare the two cases). (OK, there are minor exceptions to that, but they are not the rule!) If your textbook does, that indicates its (low) quality, at least when it comes to time series...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have learnt a lot (: